# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la cantidad de X elementos dentro de un objeto?

Tags: javascript

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
{
    nombre: "Juan",
    permiso: 2045,
    permiso2: 4631,
    permiso3: 16321,
}
{
    nombre: "Pepe",
    permiso1: 656512
}
{
    nombre: "Maria",
    permiso: 465132,
    permiso2: 41321
}
```

Y lo que yo quiero hacer en una tabla HTML es mostrar:

```
Nombre | Cantidad de permisos
Juan   | 3
Pepe   | 1
Maria  | 2
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener la cantidad de X elementos dentro de un objeto?

Comment: Eso no es JSON, tiene pinta de querer ser un array de objetos en todo caso. ¿Puedes darle el formato correcto?

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la cantidad de permisos, primero se hace `Object.keys(x)`, obteniendo la lista completa de propiedades. Es decir, el nombre y los permisos. Luego filtro por las propiedades que comiencen con `permiso`, es decir, `permiso1`, `permiso2`, y para esto uso una expresión regular `x.match(/^permiso/i)`. Entonces una vez filtrado obtengo su longitud.

```
var matriz = array_de_objetos.map(x=>[
  x.nombre
  , Object.keys(x)
    .filter(x=>x.match(/^permiso/i)).length
])
```

La intención es convertir el objeto a una matriz, es decir, un array de arrays, que es equivalente a la tabla.

```
[ [ "Juan"  ,          "3"           ]
, [ "Pepe"  ,          "1"           ]
, [ "María" ,          "2"           ] ]
```

Para agregar el encabezado a la tabla simplemente agrego un array al principio de la matriz, que es la fila principal. Esto lo hago mediante `unshift`:

```
matriz.unshift( ["Nombre", "Cantidad de permisos"] )
```

La matriz quedaría así:

```
[ [ "Nombre", "Cantidad de permisos" ]
, [ "Juan"  ,          "3"           ]
, [ "Pepe"  ,          "1"           ]
, [ "María" ,          "2"           ] ]
```

Para recorrer las columnas y las filas de la matriz uso `map`.

1. Primero creo la tabla mediante `var table = document.createElement("table")`.
2. Luego para crear las filas hago `var tr = document.createElement("tr")`
3. Ahora hago las columnas de las filas, es decir, las celdas, mediante `var td = document.createElement("td")`.
4. Agrego el valor a la celda `td.innerHTML = y`
5. Voy agregando cada valor a la tabla mediante `appendChild`.

   5.1. Agrego a la fila una celda mediante `tr.appendChild(td)`.

   5.2. Agrego a la tabla una fila mediante `tabla.appendChild(tr)`.

   5.3. Agrego al elemento que quiero, la tabla. En este caso el elemento que quiero es `document.body`. Lo hago mediante `document.body.appendChild(tabla)`.

Código de la función `crear_tabla`. Esta función crea la tabla *HTML* a partir de una `matriz`:

```
function crear_tabla(matriz){
    var tabla = document.createElement("table")
    matriz.map(x=>{
        var tr = document.createElement("tr")
        x.map(y=>{
            var td = document.createElement("td")
            td.innerHTML = y
            tr.appendChild(td)
        })
        tabla.appendChild(tr)
    })
    document.body.appendChild(tabla)
}
```

Código completo:

```js
function crear_tabla(matriz){
  var tabla = document.createElement("table")
  matriz.map(x=>{
    var tr = document.createElement("tr")
    x.map(y=>{
      var td = document.createElement("td")
      td.innerHTML = y
      tr.appendChild(td)
    })
    tabla.appendChild(tr)
  })
  document.body.appendChild(tabla)
}

var array_de_objetos = [
  {nombre: "Juan", permiso: 2045, permiso2: 4631, permiso3: 16321}
  ,{nombre: "Pepe", permiso1: 656512}
  ,{nombre: "María",permiso: 465132,permiso2: 41321}
]

var matriz = array_de_objetos.map(x=>[
  x.nombre
  , Object.keys(x)
    .filter(x=>x.match(/^permiso/i)).length
])

var títulos = ["Nombre", "Cantidad de permisos"]
matriz.unshift(títulos)

crear_tabla(matriz)
```

```css
table,tr,td{
  border-style: groove;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto sea lo que buscas amigo saludos

```js
var objeto = [{
    nombre: "Juan",
    permiso: 2045,
    permiso2: 4631,
    permiso3: 16321,
},
{
    nombre: "Pepe",
    permiso1: 656512
},
{
    nombre: "Maria",
    permiso: 465132,
    permiso2: 41321
}]

for (var i = 0; i < objeto.length; i++) {
  var numero = 0
  for (var variable in objeto[i]) {
    numero++
  }
    var texto = JSON.stringify(objeto[i])
    
    $("#tabla").find("tbody").append("<tr><td>"+objeto[i].nombre+"</td><td>"+(numero-1)+"</td></tr>")
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

una forma seria trabajar los datos que provees, convirtiendolo en otro arreglo de que tenga solamente la informacion de nombre y cantidad para que puedas usar ng-repeat para lograr imprimirlos.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.datos = [{
      nombre: "Juan",
      permiso: 2045,
      permiso2: 4631,
      permiso3: 16321,
    },
    {
      nombre: "Pepe",
      permiso1: 656512
    },
    {
      nombre: "Maria",
      permiso: 465132,
      permiso2: 41321
    }
  ];
  $scope.permisos;
  getPermisos();

  function getPermisos() {
    var retornoPermisos = [];
    $scope.datos.forEach(function(current) {
      var cantidad = Object.values(current).length - 1;

      retornoPermisos.push({
        nombre: current.nombre,
        cantidad: cantidad
      });
    })
    $scope.permisos = retornoPermisos;



  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="n in permisos ">
    {{n.nombre}} {{n.cantidad}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar un [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) y retornan un nuevo array de objetos que necesita buscándo la cantidad de propiedades sin contar con el nombre con [Object.keys(obj)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys).

```js
const objects = [
    {
        nombre: "Juan",
        permiso: 2045,
        permiso2: 4631,
        permiso3: 16321,
    },
    {
        nombre: "Pepe",
        permiso1: 656512
    },
    {
        nombre: "Maria",
        permiso: 465132,
        permiso2: 41321
    }
];

const filtered = objects.map(obj => ({
  nombre: obj.nombre, permisos: Object.keys(obj).length - 1
}));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que solo vas a tener nombre como propiedad y el resto es permiso1, permiso2, etc. Es sencillo como solo hacer:

objects.map(persona => ({
  ...persona,
   cantidadPermisos: Object.keys(persona) - 1,
}));

Asi tendras una copia del arreglo pero con la diferencia que tendras una propiedad más que tiene las cantidad de permisos.  Disculpa por no ponerlo con en code, estoy desde el telefono

Answer (score -1):

Podrías usar un arreglo para almacenar los permisos, te dejo un ejemplo:

Este es tu JSON:

```
var json = [{
    nombre: "Juan",
    permiso: 2045,
    permiso2: 4631,
    permiso3: 16321,
},
{
    nombre: "Pepe",
    permiso1: 656512
},
{
    nombre: "Maria",
    permiso: 465132,
    permiso2: 41321
}];
```

El cual podrías reemplazar por un formato como:

```
var json = [{
    nombre: "Juan",
    permisos: [2045, 4631, 16321]
},
{
    nombre: "Pepe",
    permisos: [656512]
},
{
    nombre: "Maria",
    permisos: [465132, 41321]
}];
```

Ahora suponiendo que tienes una tabla como esta o similar:

```
<table id="tabla">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Aquí insertaremos las filas necesarias para mostrar la información -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ahora con una función insertaremos unas filas dentro de la tabla.

```
//Suponiendo que el objeto JSON ya está definido.
//Seleccionamos la tabla donde mostraremos la información
var mi_tabla = document.getElementById("tabla").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

//Esta es una función de apoyo para crear una fila e insertar la dentro de una tabla
function insertarFila(nombre, cantidad, tabla){
    //Creamos la fila
    var fila = document.createElement("tr"),
        celda_nombre = document.createElement("td"),
        celda_cantidad = document.createElement("td");

    //Armamos la fila
    celda_nombre.textContent = nombre;
    celda_cantidad.textContent = cantidad;

    fila.appendChild( celda_nombre );
    fila.appendChild( celda_cantidad );

    tabla.appendChild( fila );
}

//Recorreremos nuestro objeto JSON
for(var i=0, objeto_actual; objeto_actual=json[i]; i++){
    //Aquí dentro, la variable "objeto_actual" es igual a un objeto de "json" por cada ciclo.

    //Aquí NO obtendremos la cantidad de X elementos que se repiten, en su lugar, usaremos la propiedad "length" del objeto Array "permisos" que está definido por cada objeto.
    //Usaremos nuestra función de apoyo para mostrar la información

    insertarFila(objeto_actual.nombre, objeto_actual.permisos.length, mi_tabla);
}
```

Espero y te funcione, saludos!